# How to remove quotes from the firebug

Tags: html, firebug

how can i remove the textarea quotes in the google chrome firebug

```
<textarea>
"

sometext

"
</textarea>
```

those double quotes can be removed in firebug for example in google chrome firebug?

Comment: or how can i prevent to save the data like a text?

Comment: in firefox firebug there is no double quote